# Gyroscope usage on android issues

Tags: android, opengl-es

Okay so i am working on something with OpenGL ES and im wanting to move something with the Device Orientation now its working half fine... I mean the movements work but for some reasons still get out of the boundries i give it. This is my code:

```
        float pos = Triangle.getPosX();
        float pos2 = Triangle.getPosY();
        float pos3 = Triangle.getPosZ();


        float pos4 = Triangle.getPosX2();
        float pos5 = Triangle.getPosY2();
        float pos6 = Triangle.getPosZ2();
         switch (event.sensor.getType())
         {
            case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:

                if(event.values[0] > 1)
                {
                    if(pos < 0)
                    {
                        Triangle.setPosX(pos - 0.1f);
                        Triangle.setPosY(pos2 - 0.1f);
                        Triangle.setPosZ(pos3 - 0.1f);
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(" , " +event.values[0] + pos);
                if(event.values[0] < -1)
                {
                    if(pos > -3)
                    {
                        Triangle.setPosX(pos + 0.1f );
                        Triangle.setPosY(pos2 + 0.1f);
                        Triangle.setPosZ(pos3 + 0.1f);
                    }
                }
            break;
```

I dont know why it can still get out of the screen. Anyone?

Comment: Your question is hard to answer for a number of reasons. (a) Your code is poorly formatted. (b) You include code that is not relevant. (c) The intention of you code is not always clear. You should try to explain what you expect each `if()` block to achieve.

Comment: Sorry. My if(pos < 0) is trying to achieve that the triangle wont go out further then i can see on the screen, so is the other one

Answer (score 0):

Your code in Plain English does this:

> ```
> If posx is less than 0
>     Decrease posx. Without bounds.
>
> If posx is greater than -3 
>     Increase it. Without bounds.
> ```

A maybe better thing to do is this:

> ```
> If posx is less than 0
>     Increase posx.
>
> If posx is greater than -3 
>     Decrease posx.
> ```

for example with Java code like this. 
I renamed some variables to make their meaning more clear.

```java
float posx = Triangle.getPosX();
float posy = Triangle.getPosY();
float posz = Triangle.getPosZ();

switch (event.sensor.getType())
{
    case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:

    float accelx = event.values[0];
    if(accelx > 1 && posx < 0)
    {
        Triangle.setPosX(posx + 0.1f);
        Triangle.setPosY(posy + 0.1f);
        Triangle.setPosZ(posz + 0.1f);
    }

    if(accelx < -1 && posx > -3)
    {
        Triangle.setPosX(posx - 0.1f);
        Triangle.setPosY(posy - 0.1f);
        Triangle.setPosZ(posz - 0.1f);
    }
    break;
}
```

Comment: For some reason first few seconds it works then it bugs up and is abled to flow out of the boundries. And also sometimes it just randomly moves. Weirdly enough it works fine vertically. And its using the same thing as in my original post.